# Error following MapBox Navigation Guide

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm following a guide by MapBox on implementing Navigation into an Android App. On the last step of Display User Location, when adding the following code to the MainActivity.java:

```
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
@Override
public void onMapReady(final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
    map = mapboxMap;
    enableLocationPlugin();
};
});
```

I have multiple errors when running the app. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GUxw.png)

1. mapView.getMapAsync has a cannot resolve symbol error.
2. Several errors where Android Studio is confused by the parentheses when it is expecting a ; or {.
3. Following guide I have already imported all the plug-ins and sdks needed but the import statement for the OnMapReadyCallback function (used above) seems to be inactive as Android studio tells me it is an unused import statement. [Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOmOZ.png)

There is a lack of documentation for this error however similar problems have been documented with Google Maps. Their implementation is different to that of MapBox's so their solution is not compatible.

How can I resolve these errors and most importantly be able to run the app and continue on with the tutorial guide?

Full MainActivity.Java Code can be found here.

```
    package com.mettre.mettre;

import java.util.List;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

// classes needed to add location layer
import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapboxMap;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;

import android.location.Location;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.camera.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.LocationLayerMode;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.locationlayer.LocationLayerPlugin;
import com.mapbox.services.android.location.LostLocationEngine;
import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationViewOptions;
import com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEngine;
import com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEngineListener;
import com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.location.LocationEnginePriority;
import com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.permissions.PermissionsListener;
import com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.permissions.PermissionsManager;


public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationEngineListener, PermissionsListener{

    private MapView mapView;
    // variables for adding location layer
    private MapboxMap map;
    private PermissionsManager permissionsManager;
    private LocationLayerPlugin locationPlugin;
    private LocationEngine locationEngine;
    private Location originLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    // Add the mapView's own lifecycle methods to the activity's lifecycle methods
    /*@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    */

    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    private void enableLocationPlugin() {
        // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
        if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
            // Create an instance of LOST location engine
            initializeLocationEngine();

            locationPlugin = new LocationLayerPlugin(mapView, map, locationEngine);
            locationPlugin.setLocationLayerEnabled(LocationLayerMode.TRACKING);
        } else {
            permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
            permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    private void initializeLocationEngine() {
        locationEngine = new LostLocationEngine(MainActivity.this);
        locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationEngine.activate();

        Location lastLocation = locationEngine.getLastLocation();
        if (lastLocation != null) {
            originLocation = lastLocation;
            setCameraPosition(lastLocation);
        } else {
            locationEngine.addLocationEngineListener(this);
        }
    }

    private void setCameraPosition(Location location) {
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExplanationNeeded(List<String> permissionsToExplain) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionResult(boolean granted) {
        if (granted) {
            enableLocationPlugin();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    public void onConnected() {
        locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            originLocation = location;
            setCameraPosition(location);
            locationEngine.removeLocationEngineListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings( {"MissingPermission"})
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (locationEngine != null) {
            locationEngine.requestLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (locationPlugin != null) {
            locationPlugin.onStart();
        }
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (locationEngine != null) {
            locationEngine.removeLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (locationPlugin != null) {
            locationPlugin.onStop();
        }
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
        if (locationEngine != null) {
            locationEngine.deactivate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            map = mapboxMap;
            enableLocationPlugin();
        };
    });

}
```

[Here is the errors from Android Studio when compiling:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vSEA.png)

Comment: Please post the exact exceptions instead of a description of the exceptions.

Comment: @dazza5000 updated question with your suggestions

Comment: You have syntax errors in your code according to Android Studio. You have a semi-colon or brace missing or in the wrong place.